# Implementing Strongly Typed Ids and Hilo strategy via Entityframework core

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.2, hilo

I'm working on a project in which instead of using primitive types like Int as Id,  "Strongly Typed" are used, like CategoryId object. I want to use EntityFramework Core alongside with HiLo strategy, but it seems that entityframework just supports Hilo for Integer fields/properties. I need to know whether entityframework supports Hilo on strongly typed Ids or not. And if Yes, how I should configure it.
Thanks in advance

Update:
For the sake of clarifying what exactly I did, assuming there is a class named "Task" including a strongly-typed Id named "TaskId". I use Fluent API to configure this entity as below:

```
class TaskConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Task>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Task> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.TaskId);
        builder.Property(e => e.TaskId).HasConversion(t => t.id, id => new TaskId(id));
    }
}
```

Still every thing is well. But if I decide to use Hi-Lo strategy for entity "Task" the problem goes to begin. I use ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo() method after HasConversion() and get error by the time I'm adding migration, says that this method is only applicable to properties having integer type!
I don't know whether it is practical or not, using Hi-Lo with Strongly-Typed Ids. And if it is possible what the solution is.

Comment: What is a "CategoryId object"? I think you should first show how you manage to get EF working with non-primitive keys anyway. We have nothing to go by.

Comment: **CategoryId** is a **Strongly Typed ID**. You can find more details about what a strongly type id is here : [link](https://www.seeitsharp.pl/2018/11/strongly-typed-identifiers-dot-net/).

Comment: Which I assumed, still, a [mcve] would help. Don't expect much input without it.

Comment: First, we are not supposed to know a term that some person used in a blog. Second, "value objects", "strongly typed ids" and other "cool" DDD/OOP things doesn't play well with EF (Core). Hi/Lo value generation is just one of the problematic areas (and you are right, currently it doesn't support *user defined* types), and I highly doubt the concept works at all in queries, change tracking etc. (which I guess was behind the @Gert comment).

Comment: If you have managed it to work in all other places (e.g. mapping to db table column, PK, FK, querying etc.) and the only problem is the value generation, please provide a full sample entity with "strongly typed id" model and mapping, and we can take a look if the value generation can be solved.

Comment: So I think I have to use primitive types as ID if I want to use them with entity framework. Additionally, Strongly Typed ID is not just a term in someone's blog and If you do some search, you will find a lot of articles about it. Thank you guys to take time to read and answer.